# How to get cell value not dataset value in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am showing `'-'` when dataset field value is `NULL`.

I am setting Alignment property of each cell and wondering if there is any quick way of doing it by checking cell text instead of dataset field value? Like if cell text is showing up `'-'` then make it in center otherwise set it to right, and i can easily copy and paste it on all cells.

```
=IIF(Fields!PercVisitsWithReports.Value IS NOTHING , "Center", "Right")
```

Answer (score 1):

In a SSRS Tablix, each cell has a name. You can acces its value by using the **ReportItems** comand. Here is an example:

```
ReportItems!CellName.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=IIF(isnothing(Fields!PercVisitsWithReports.Value), "Center", "Right")
```

the `isnothing(expr)` returns true if the expr is null.

Comment: You can also write this as =Iif(IsNothing(*Me*.Value), "Center", "Right") - using Me.Value references the value of the current cell, so the expression can be copied to multiple cells with needing to be altered. (Note this works in 2005, 2008 R2 and 2012, but not in 2008 due to a bug).

Comment: I am using SSRS 2008 R2 but it is not working. Get this error "The TextAlign expression for the paragraph ‘ClientWithPO.Paragraphs[0]’ contains "Me.Value". "Me.Value" is not valid in the context of a paragraph."

Comment: This expression works fine for color =IIF(Me.Value > 0,"RED","GREEN") but me.value is not working for Text Align